# Was there any christian church that kept the Passover before the 1900?

Tags: history, church-history, passover

I was taught that after the Council of Nicea no christian church kept the Passover on the 14th of Nisan. Is there any truth to that? Is there a church in the middle ages that kept the Christian Passover on the 14th of Nisan? I've tried researching online but no luck. Thanks!

Comment: Kept Passover in the sense of doing a Jewish Seder? or in the sense of tying the date of Easter to the date of Passover in the Jewish calendar? EO date of Easter is still based on the Passover date, and thus sometimes a week ahead or behind Western Easter.

Comment: The Middle Ages did not stretch to 1900. Maybe get the dates sorted out. Do you regard only the religious groups that accepted the Council of Nicea as Christian?

Comment: @david brainerd: Tying the date of Easter to the Jewish Calendar.

Comment: @gideonmarx, yes, I understand that, it was just an example. By Christian I mean anybody that followed Jesus, even if didn't accept the Council of Nicea

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know no Christian Churches except Jewish ones kept the Passover, as it is a Jewish holiday. You probably refer to the timing of Easter.

The Council of Nicaea ruled that Easter should be celebrated on the first Sunday on/after the first full moon on/after the vernal equinox. Sometimes it matched the Jewish Passover sunday and sometimes it did not, because the Christian system mixed both solar and lunar calendars to determine the date. For more info, see

http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/determining-easter-date.html

Comment: There are some christian churches that keep Easter on the 14th of Nisan. I'm asking if there were any. I know now there are many